# OnClick event on checkbox is not working in IE after replacing innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am creating a dynamic checkbox by setting the innerHTML inside the div. This checkbox has onclick event on it. The code works fine in all browsers except IE8.

Looks like IE is not binding events after setting innerHTML. Is there a way to rebind the event ?

Below is the innerHTML code.

```
<INPUT id=Animal onclick=\"updateHTML();\" name=Control value=Animal type=checkbox uncheckedValue=\"0\" checkedValue=\"1\">
<INPUT id=Food onclick=\"updateHTML();\" name=Control value=Food type=checkbox uncheckedValue=\"0\" checkedValue=\"1\">
```

Below is complete code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
        function updateHTML()
        {
            alert('updateHTML');
        }
        function changeEvent()
        {
            var innerhtml="\r\n<TBODY id=originalDiv><TR>\r\n<TD title=\"\">\r\n<INPUT id=Animal onclick=\"updateHTML();\" name=Control value=Animal type=checkbox uncheckedValue=\"0\" checkedValue=\"1\">Animal\r\n<INPUT id=Food onclick=\"updateHTML();\" name=Control value=Food type=checkbox uncheckedValue=\"0\" checkedValue=\"1\">Food\r\n</TD></TR></TBODY>";
            var originalDiv=document.getElementById('originalDiv');
            var temp = originalDiv.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = '<table>' + innerhtml + '</table>';
            originalDiv.replaceChild(temp.firstChild, originalDiv.firstChild);
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <TABLE>
        <TBODY id ="originalDiv">
            <TR>
                <TD vAlign=middle>
                    <INPUT id=Bird onclick=\"updateHTML();\" name=Control value=Bird type=checkbox uncheckedValue=\"0\" checkedValue=\"1\">Bird
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
        <TBODY id="submit">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <input type=button value="Submit" onclick="changeEvent()">
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
<BODY>
```

Comment: what does updateHTML do? Can you show the code?

Comment: updateHTML has nothing but an alert.

Comment: ok then can you show the code of the creating the checkbox?

Comment: You'll be much better served by binding the events unobtrusively, with `element.onclick = function() {...}` instead of using the elements' `onclick` attribute.

Comment: does IE8 debugger give you any errors?

Comment: @Boaz I don't know what handler will be on click, as all these innerHTML will be generated by third party framework. I have simplified it to make it understand better.

Comment: @suhaskhot A possible workaround can be to parse the generated HTML, remove and extract the `onclick` attributes and use their values to bind the events properly.

Comment: Yes I also thought of same but this will be lot of overhead. I just to want to see if we could do this easily.

Comment: @Huangism There are no errors in IE.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix this:

- Add a doctype. It's important for IE
- Add an html end tag at the end of the document
- Close all your input tags, like this:

`<input type="checkbox" id="Bird" value="1" />`

- If you use non html attributes, use the "data-" prefix:

`<input type="checkbox" id="Bird" value="1" data-unckecked-value="0" data-checked-value="1" />`

Comment: This should probably be a comment, as it does not directly relate to the issue.

Comment: a bit longer for a comment... And the problem can comes from unclosed input tags.

Comment: First of all this code is not written by someone. It is getting generated by some Third party Java library. From what I can say is that the code is generated by JAVA classes.
Actually this code is injected into an JSP through javascript.

Comment: @gtournie - That may be, but long as it is, it's still not an answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: You probably have some options to make your code cleaner. Is there one to generate XHTML? To add a doctype?

Comment: @Boaz - IE can be really unpredicatble if you don't do things "clean". So I really think it can make the difference and resolve the issue. If it doesn't I'll remove my post, no problem ;-)

Comment: I do have it we are rewriting the code. But this application needs to have workaround till we put new code.

Comment: @gtournie Tried adding doctype. But no luck
Also confirm that all the input tags are closed. 
Html end tag was already there I missed out while copying. But still no luck.

Comment: One more thing I notice that If I go to IE debugger and change value of any property then it start working fine. 

Looks like dom is getting initialize properly and it start working fine.